# Different kinds of sport

Tags: word-choice

Should I use "sports" or "sport" in my sentence? Is "sports" wrong because "kinds" makes it clear that I am not talking about one kind of sport. Would it be possible to use "different kind"?

"She has played different kinds of sport(s)".

Comment: Just say "She has played different sports."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are regional usages involved here. UK English and English spoken in places based on it use "sport": "And here for your update on the world of sport is Billy..." US English uses "sports": "Gatorade is my favorite sports drink." So either choice could be correct *based on the region*, but they're not interchangeable within a region.

Answer (score 0):

"different kinds of sport" and "different kinds of sports" are both correct. "Sport" can be used as both a mass noun and a countable noun. I would say that "different kinds of sports" sounds a little more natural to me, but they both work.

I don't think there is any way "different kind of sport(s)" could work in this context. You are talking about multiple types of sports, so "kind" needs to be plural.